# For loop which excludes both start and end of a range

Tags: python, for-loop, range

I need to write an algorithm that can print a range of 2 given numbers from the user and exclude them.

This is the code that I have so far yet this will exclude only the second number.

```
x = int(input("Input the first number for the range: "))
n = int(input("Input the second number for the range: "))

if (x and n != 0):
    for num in range(x, n):
        print(num)
```

How can I make it exclude the first number, too?

Comment: `range` includes the start and excludes the stop. Use `range(x+1, n)`. Also while `if (x and n != 0):` will check that both numbers are not null, I suspect you misunderstood how this works. `if x and n:` would work.

Comment: Look at the documentation for [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range). If you want to exclude the beginning, start from the next larger number - `x + 1`.

Comment: You might also be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-for-equality-against-a-single-value. `if (x and n != 0)` isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: Did you notice what happened when the input for the first number is zero?

Answer (score 0):

*range* can be invoked in 1 of two ways:

```
range(stop)
range(start, stop, [step])
```

You need to be aware that the *stop* value is excluded but *start* is included.

Therefore, for your use-case it's as simple as:

```
x = int(input("Input the first number for the range: "))
n = int(input("Input the second number for the range: "))


for num in range(x+1, n):
    print(num)
```

**Note:**

Input validation not included